# jquery filter function used to filter a class

Tags: jquery, html

A set of tr is there. and some tr pocess a class `dblist_selected` . I need to filter out the `tr` elements contain that class.I wrote a jquery code for that but its not working.

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tbodyDashBoard">
        <tr id="tr0" class="heading">
            <th>heading</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr1" class="itemrow dblist_selected">
            <td>itemname1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2" class="itemrow dblist_selected">
            <td>itemname2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr3" class="itemrow">
            <td>itemname3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr4" class="itemrow">
            <td>itemname4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr5" class="itemrow">
            <td>itemname5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr6" class="itemrow">
            <td>itemname6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr7" class="itemrow">
            <td>itemname7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the jquery code statement. I need the returned object in the variable selRow

```
var selRow = $("#divGridContainer").find("#tbodyDashBoard tr").filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('class') == 'dblist_selected';
});
```

Is there any error in the code. How can I achieve my goal

Comment: Why not simple `$("#tbodyDashBoard tr.dblist_selected")`

Comment: It worked. Initially I was filtering out with background-color, so followed the same step even after changing the filter parameter for this.

Comment: please give id of your <tbody id="tbodyDashBoard"> element

Comment: @ Ankit Kathiriya Sorry by mistake I eliminated here. It is there in my original markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem in the code is that the value of the attribute class is compared to the classname, so if the element contains other class, the condition will not be satisfied.

```
var selRow = $("#divGridContainer").find("#tbodyDashBoard tr").filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('class') == 'dblist_selected';
});
```

For the elements the `$(this).attr('class')` will give string as `'itemrow dblist_selected'` which is not equal to the string `'dblist_selected'`. So, filtering will return no elements  in the `selRow` variable.

**Solution:**

Use [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to check if an element is having specified class.

```
var selRow = $("#divGridContainer").find("#tbodyDashBoard tr").filter(function () {
    return $(this).hasClass('dblist_selected');
});
```

---

**There is no need to use `filter`**, use descendant selector.

```
var selRow = $("#divGridContainer #tbodyDashBoard tr.dblist_selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rather use class selector along with classname to target element with class `dblist_selected`:

```
var selRow = $("#divGridContainer").find("#tbodyDashBoard tr.dblist_selected")
```

Comment: Thankyou!! this worked. But why my code statement is not working. is that not a proper way for doing that

Answer (score 1):

You may access these elements directly:

```
$("#divGridContainer").find("#tbodyDashBoard tr.dblist_selected").each( function (index, element) {
   // do stuff with element - jQuery(element)...
});
```